# What personalisation string does the Salesforce field 'et4ae5__MergeId__c' relate to in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

within the individual email result object (et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c) there is a field called: et4ae5__MergeId__c

What ID does this relate to in a Marketing Cloud send?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MergeId is populated with either:

- Contact ID + Email Send Record ID (happens for batch sends)*or*
- A numerical Id generated by Marketing Cloud (triggered sends)

Merge ID is not accessible out-of-the-box within the Marketing Cloud's Data Views. You can engage Salesforce Services to have a Custom Data View created that exposes the merge id so that it can become accessible via Query Activities etc.

The Merge Id is the unique key used when loading (i.e. Upserting) tracking details from Marketing Cloud to Core.

Comment: Thanks @Kenneth for your answer. I was hoping to do lookup on the individual email result object (et4ae5__IndividualEmailResult__c) to associate it with another SF record. So this is proving to be quite a difficult task, as there is no unique ID I can get from the send to lookup perform the lookup.

Comment: Indeed Richard, you would need to do this via an ETL tool. I.e. some combination of a Send Log + Custom Data View + SQL and then populate the date.

Comment: the challenge is you don't have the normal Job Id + Batch Id data on the IER record, hence the need for the custom send log :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer @KennethWagner - any idea what is the rough cost of enabling this custom log? :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if it provisionable anymore via a Custom data View (i actually haven't checked), would check via support if possible. The future of MC (journeys only, relying on Triggered Sends infrastructure - if my memory serve), may also give warrant to another design than historically what was possible vs. business requirements :)

Comment: Thanks, @KennethWagner, we will check with support. I need to "fix" IERs and seems this would be the best way to match IERs with tracking data in SFMC :-)