# Individual Email Result ID store in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

In sales cloud individual email result records get created after sending emails from the marketing cloud, so can we store that IER ID back in the marketing cloud? or is it available already in the data view?

Thanks,
Akash

Comment: Why would you want it back in MC? All of the data is already available  in MC data views, related to the subscriber key (Contact/Lead ID)

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

The IER IDs are not stored in Marketing Cloud.

If needed, you could potentially synch the IER object back to Marketing Cloud through the [Synchronized Data Sources](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_co_synchronized_data_sources.htm&language=en_US), but the question is why would you want to do that?

As Lukas mentioned, all the tracking data for your emails is already available in Marketing Cloud in the [Data Views](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_as_data_views.htm&language=en_US).

On top of that, note that there is no direct link or a common ID between the IER and the data stored in Data Views - this can be [enabled by Salesforce Support](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245474/what-personalisation-string-does-the-salesforce-field-et4ae5-mergeid-c-relat) at an extra cost, most probably not worth it, as most things related to tracking can be accomplished using Data Views on their own.

Comment: HI All, Thanks for checking, As you, guys know when we sent an email then IER record gets created and you will see the same in the related list of contact or lead so now i am trying to capture the response using trigger send and sending it to sales cloud (using AMPscript) storing into a custom object and hence to lookup these responses to IER i want IER id in marketing cloud so it will reduce my work but unfortunately as you said its not already in MC, we need sync.

Comment: Yes, in that case you’ll have to synch it.