How to re-import IERs into Salesforce - getting duplicate errors on et4ae5__MergeId__c field
We purged IER records (IndividualEmailResults, which is data from Marketing Cloud about emails sent there to contacts from SF) from Salesforce about nine months ago due to the large amount of data storage they were consuming.
Now the business users would like that data back. I have the backup and started re-importing using data loader, but I got an error for every single record
duplicate value found: et4ae5__MergeId__c duplicates value on record with id: a1V3l00000E3X6TEAV

Does anyone know how I can workaround this issue?
Thank you!

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/245474/what-personalisation-string-does-the-salesforce-field-et4ae5-mergeid-c-relat is a good start, then resolve conflicts

Super embarrassing, but these records were already there :(

Things like this happen to every one of use once in a while :-)
